# Rails exclude attribute when creating a copy record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code in my `jobplan` controller. It's creating copies of `jobtasks`.

This is the code:

```
@jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
  @jobtask = Jobtask.where("id = ?", jobtask)
  @task = Task.create(@jobtask.attributes)
end
```

Question 1:

Is there a way to exclude a `jobtask` attribute from the new `task`?

Question 2:

What about adding a fixed attribute to the new `task` that's not in `jobtask`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
@jobplan.jobtasks.each do |jobtask|
  jobtask_attrs = jobtask.attributes
  jobtask_attrs.delete(:some_attribute) # Question 1
  jobtask_attrs.merge!({ additionnal_attribute: "Hello world!" }) # Question 2
  Task.create(jobtask_attrs)
end
```

**Notice:** If it is the `id` attribute that you want to take off the attributes, don't worry about that, ActiveRecord will ignore it when creating a new record ;)

I refactored your code to be more efficient / readable, feel free to ask questions if you need ;-)

Refactored:

- `@jobplan.jobtasks` should already returns `Jobtask` object belonging to this `Jobplan`, so no need to make another query to the DB to find it back again
- Your shared variable like `@task` would be rewrote at each loop of the array, eventually create a shared variable `@tasks` and fill it with the tasks created.

Comment: Thanks for the reputation @Reddirt, You should receive a Gold Badge, something like "Made 30% of the reputation of user MrYoshiji"! Ahah

Comment: Regarding the Notice - if the id attribute is a UUID (eg using Postgres) the new record will have the exact same UUID as the one you copied from. So you should really remove the id first in such a case.

Comment: @rmcsharry isn't there a unique constraint on the DB level for that UUID? I mean, I agree that you should remove that attribute from the form so it won't be used in the insert statement, but the DB must probably complain about a duplicated UUID.

Comment: @MrYoshiji AFAIK postgres (and most rdbms) don't support constraints at the database level. I tried googling it and came up with nothing.

Comment: @rmcsharry PostgreSQL seems to support the unique constraint : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: @MrYoshiji All those are constraints at the table level. The only way I know to ensure two tables do not have the same UUID as a primary key is to fire a trigger on both update and insert and then run a query, but that would be a terrible idea and not perform well on large datasets.

Comment: this was a concise and awesome reply +1

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:

`@jobtask.attributes` returns a hash. So you can do everything that you can on a hash

```
Task.create(@jobtask.attributes.except(:attribute_name))
```

Question 2:

```
Task.create(@jobtask.attributes.merge(:attribute_name => "value"))
```

Comment: Nope, wont work: `hash.delete(:key)` returns the value deleted, not the hash after the deletion

Comment: Oh nice, Thanks for sharing the `.except(:key)` method, thought it was only for Ruby 2.0!